# Unable to get the unread mails from office365 mail box using PHP imap_headers() function

Tags: php, email, outlook, imap, office365

I was trying to read the gmail mail box using `imap_headers` and `imap_header()` function available in php, it was working fine without any problems. Here in gmail `imap_header()` function gives the count of only un-read mails and `imap_headers($message_number)` function would take the message number as input and would return the header information of the mail. Executing `imap_fetchstructure()` and `imap_fetchbody()` the message would be marked as read and that message would not come in the next run, since it was marked as read.

Now when I am using office365 account the function `imap_header()` is returning the count of all mails in the inbox and not the unread mails count, also as contrary in previous case `imap_fetchstructure()` and `imap_fetchbody()` are not marking the mail as read and hence the read mails also get tracked in the next job cycles.

Any inputs on this is really helpfull.....Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

The `imap_header()` will give you all the mail as its definition.
You should use `imap_search()` to filter out the unread mail.
You can use the below code:

```
$imapobj = imap_open(SERVER,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
$result = imap_search($imapobj, 'UNSEEN');
foreach($result as $res=>$value){   
      $maildetails = imap_headerinfo($value);  
      $status = imap_setflag_full($imapobj, $value, "\\Seen");
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful, thanks! More info on `imap_search()` here http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-search.php